# Is it possible to predefine a winning number in Solidity and make it visible after some condition?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, evm

[image]

I want contract to predifine winning boxes, is it possible to achieve this functionality solidity, so no one can detect which box is the winning box?

If so, how can I predefine winning boxes which will be unreadeable until the user opens a specific box?

I tried to use `block.timestamp` to randomly choose winning boxes upon contract creation, but hacker can replicate block.timestamp and determine which box is the winning box.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a trusted party, you can hash the winning number (with a salt so people don't brute force it), then reveal it after a certain point. This has an obvious disadvantage that whoever hashed the number knows the winning number.

Your question implies you are looking for *randomness*, so you can used established randomness patterns like commit reveal or chainlink VRF. With commit reveal, when someone plays the game, they commit that a future blockhash will be the random number. A block producer can tamper with the hash to a certain degree, so if you are worried about that, use chainlink VRF.

Comment: The game will have only one instance, Imagine 100k boxes and everyone can open it, winning numbers must be predefined but when user A unlocks a certain box he will know if he won or not. Is this achievable?

Comment: By definition, a smart contract cannot hold private information, it has to be public so anyone can validate the blockchain. You cannot find out in the same transaction if you picked a predetermined winning box. Otherwise, the player could simulate the outcome of the transaction before trying the box.

Answer (score 0):

Make your boxes to be the **Schrödinger boxes** - winners and losers at the same time. When a user selects a box and sends the Transaction to your contract - request a **random number** from Chainlink and make it to a winner or loser box.